# How should I interpret this for loop in pseudo-code?

Tags: pseudocode

I'm looking at the following pseudo-code:

```
for i = 1,2,... do
    ...
    for j = 1,2,...,i-1 do
        ...
    end for
end for
```

**Question:** Should the second for loop be executed when i = 1? I'm a bit confused since for i = 1 we have the statement:

```
for j = 1,2,...,0
```

Does that mean that the for loop is not executed until i = 2?

Comment: Yes, in general that's what it means.

Comment: I'd interpret it as, "Whomever wrote this pseudo-code should be slapped."

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Ok, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would read it like in C++: initialize inner loop `j=1`, then execute `if (j<=i-1)`. Thus for `i==1` the inner loop would not be executed.